# \hfil in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\begin{document}
\[\phantom{\ast}\hfil a\hfil\ast\]
As you can see, the \verb"\hfil"s get ignored… or at least the one on the right does. But if I swap \verb"\phantom" and \verb"\ast", I get:
\[\ast\hfil a\hfil\phantom{\ast},\]
where the \verb"\hfil" is still being ignored. Therefore I infer both are being ignored.
\end{document}
```

Why does that happen?

Comment: It's the same as saying `\hbox{a\hfil b}`; display math material is typeset at its natural width, so glue doesn't stretch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying `\hfil` is the same as saying `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil` or, in LaTeXspeak, `\hspace{0pt plus 1fil}`.

However, TeX uses the stretch component only if it has to. For instance, in

```
\hbox{a\hfil b} % Plain TeX
\makebox{a\hfil b} % LaTeX (or \mbox{a\hfil b})
```

the stretch component will do nothing and there will be no space between “a” and “b”. Conversely, a spacing will appear with

```
\hbox to 2cm{a\hfil b} % Plain TeX
\makebox[2cm][s]{a\hfil b} % LaTeX
```

because TeX wants to occupy the stated length.

A formula in display math is typeset at its natural width, so glue will use only the length component and not the stretch component. The length component for `\hfil` is zero.

If you want to fill all the available space, you should say

```
\[
\makebox[\displaywidth][s]{$\displaystyle\phantom{*}a\hfil{*}$}
\]
```

but it's surely better to say

```
\[
a\tag*{$*$}
\]
```

using `amsmath` features.